# Counting pairs of elements in a circular ArrayList containing -1, 0, and 1

Tags: java

I have the following method:

```
public void test() {

    List<Integer> slopeChanges = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    slopeChanges.add(0);
    slopeChanges.add(0);
    slopeChanges.add(1);
    slopeChanges.add(0);
    slopeChanges.add(1);

    List<Double> sixProbabilites = new ArrayList<Double>();

    int count_neg10 = 0, count_neg11 = 0, count_10 = 0, count_1neg1 = 0, count_0neg1 = 0, count_01 = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<slopeChanges.size(); i++) {
        if(i+1 != slopeChanges.size()) {
            if((slopeChanges.get(i) == -1) && (slopeChanges.get(i+1) == 0)) {count_neg10++;}
            else if((slopeChanges.get(i) == -1) && (slopeChanges.get(i+1) == 1)) {count_neg11++;}
            else if((slopeChanges.get(i) == 1) && (slopeChanges.get(i+1) == 0)) {count_10++;}
            else if((slopeChanges.get(i) == 1) && (slopeChanges.get(i+1) == -1)) {count_1neg1++;}
            else if((slopeChanges.get(i) == 0) && (slopeChanges.get(i+1) == -1)) {count_0neg1++;}
            else if((slopeChanges.get(i) == 0) && (slopeChanges.get(i+1) == 1)) {count_01++;}
        }else {
            if((slopeChanges.get(i) == -1) && (slopeChanges.get(0) == 0)) {count_neg10++;}
            else if((slopeChanges.get(i) == -1) && (slopeChanges.get(0) == 1)) {count_neg11++;}
            else if((slopeChanges.get(i) == 1) && (slopeChanges.get(0) == 0)) {count_10++;}
            else if((slopeChanges.get(i) == 1) && (slopeChanges.get(0) == -1)) {count_1neg1++;}
            else if((slopeChanges.get(i) == 0) && (slopeChanges.get(0) == -1)) {count_0neg1++;}
            else if((slopeChanges.get(i) == 0) && (slopeChanges.get(0) == 1)) {count_01++;}
        }
    }

    System.out.println(slopeChanges);

    if(count_neg10 != 0) {System.out.println("count_neg10 = " + count_neg10);}
    if(count_neg11 != 0) {System.out.println("count_neg11 = " + count_neg11);}
    if(count_10 != 0)    {System.out.println("count_10 = " + count_10);}
    if(count_1neg1 != 0) {System.out.println("count_1neg1 = " + count_1neg1);}
    if(count_0neg1 != 0) {System.out.println("count_0neg1 = " + count_0neg1);}
    if(count_01 != 0)    {System.out.println("count_01 = " + count_01);}

    if(count_neg10 != 0) {sixProbabilites.add((double)count_neg10 / ((double)slopeChanges.size()));}
    if(count_neg11 != 0) {sixProbabilites.add((double)count_neg11 / ((double)slopeChanges.size()));}
    if(count_10 != 0) {sixProbabilites.add((double)count_10 / ((double)slopeChanges.size()));}
    if(count_1neg1 != 0) {sixProbabilites.add((double)count_1neg1 / ((double)slopeChanges.size()));}
    if(count_0neg1 != 0) {sixProbabilites.add((double)count_0neg1 / ((double)slopeChanges.size()));}
    if(count_01 != 0) {sixProbabilites.add((double)count_01 / ((double)slopeChanges.size()));}
}
```

The `slopeChanges` list contains symbols that are either 0, 1, or -1. I would like to count frequencies of sub-blocks that are either `01, 10, -11, 1-1, -10, 0-1`. The method that I showed does what I want, for example, this block of symbols `00101` should result in `count_10 = 2` which means `10` sub-block occurs twice while `01` (i.e., `count_01 = 2`) occurs twice. Please note that the we consider the first symbol is also last.

As you can see, there are lot of duplication in the code in order to perform what I want. Is there a better way to re-write this function in a very elegant style?

Comment: are you sure of this: _this block of symbols `00101` should result in `count_10 = 2` which means 10 sub-block occurs twice_

Comment: @AdamSilenko Yes, I mentioned that we consider the first symbol is also last.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd way is to use the array with unique index calculated from current and next value:

```
public void test() {

    List<Integer> slopeChanges = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    slopeChanges.add(0);
    slopeChanges.add(0);
    slopeChanges.add(1);
    slopeChanges.add(0);
    slopeChanges.add(1);

    /*
    static final int count_neg10 = 2; // -1 + 3 * (0 + 1);
    static final int count_neg11 = 5; // -1  + 3 * (1 + 1);
    static final int count_10 = 4; // 1 + 3 * (0 + 1);
    static final int count_1neg1 = 1; // 1 + 3 * (-1 + 1);
    static final int count_0neg1 = 0; // 0  + 3 * (-1 + 1);
    static final int count_01 = 6; // 0  + 3 * (1 + 1);*/

    int[] count = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    String[] count_names = {"count_0neg1", "count_1neg1", "count_neg10", "", "count_10", "count_neg11", "count_01"};

    List<Double> sixProbabilites = new ArrayList<Double>();

    for(int i = 0, j = slopeChanges.size() -1; i<slopeChanges.size(); i++) {
      if (slopeChanges.get(i) != slopeChanges.get(j)) {
        count[slopeChanges.get(i) + 3 * (slopeChanges.get(j) + 1) ]++;
      } 
      j = i;
    }

    System.out.println(slopeChanges);

    for(int i = 0; i<7; i++) {
      if(count[i] != 0) {
        System.out.println(count_names[i] + " = " + count[i]);
        sixProbabilites.add((double)count[i] / ((double)slopeChanges.size()));
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: it return `[0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
count_10 = 2
count_01 = 2`

Answer (score 1):

#### Reducing Duplication

The first `if` statement can be removed by taking a step back and realising that what we really want is the index of the next element,
which is usually `i + 1` but wraps back around to the start of the list. We can use the modulo `%` operator to achieve this.

The inner `if-else` statements can be refined by storing the slope changes in a 2d array, imagining a chart with the x and y axis
corresponding to the current and next values of `slopeChanges` respectively.

Looping over this array (ignoring any slope changes that you're not interested in), we can both print the number of each slope change
that occurred and add the probability of it occurring to the probability array.

I also separated the core logic of the program into it's own class and method, allowing for easier re-use.

Example of changes, I took some liberties by adjusting the output text slightly, I felt it no longer made sense to print the variable names since they had been removed.

```
public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    List<Integer> slopeChanges = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    slopeChanges.add(0);
    slopeChanges.add(0);
    slopeChanges.add(1);
    slopeChanges.add(0);
    slopeChanges.add(1);

    List<Double> sixProbabilities = SlopeCounter.CalculateProbabilities(slopeChanges);
  }
}

public class SlopeCounter
{
  public static List<Double> CalculateProbabilities(List<Integer> slopeChanges)
  {
    List<Double> sixProbabilities = new ArrayList<Double>();

    int slopeChangeSize = slopeChanges.size();

    int[][] slopeChangeCounts = new int[3][3];

    for(int i = 0; i < slopeChangeSize; i++) {
        int nextIndex = (i + 1) % slopeChangeSize;

        int currentValue = slopeChanges.get(i);

        int nextValue = slopeChanges.get(nextIndex);

        // Relying on the fact that both currentValue and
        // nextValue are between -1 and 1 we can add 1 to
        // both values to store in a 2d array

        slopeChangeCounts[currentValue + 1][nextValue + 1]++;

        // This will also count non-slopes, i.e. 11, 00, -1-1,
        // but we can ignore these
    }

    System.out.println(slopeChanges);

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            if(j == k) continue; // Skip non-slopes

            int changeCount = slopeChangeCounts[j][k];

            if(changeCount == 0) continue; // Skip slopes that didnt happen

            System.out.println("Slope " + (j-1) + " to " + (k-1) + " = " + changeCount);

            sixProbabilities.add((double)changeCount / ((double)slopeChangeSize));
        }
    }

    return sixProbabilities;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove some `else` using two indexes, and aggregate `if`.

```
public void test() {

    List<Integer> slopeChanges = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    slopeChanges.add(0);
    slopeChanges.add(0);
    slopeChanges.add(1);
    slopeChanges.add(0);
    slopeChanges.add(1);

    List<Double> sixProbabilites = new ArrayList<Double>();

    int count_neg10 = 0, count_neg11 = 0, count_10 = 0, count_1neg1 = 0, count_0neg1 = 0, count_01 = 0;

    for(int i = 0, j = slopeChanges.size() -1; i<slopeChanges.size(); i++) {
      if (slopeChanges.get(j) == -1) {
        if (slopeChanges.get(i) == 0) {count_neg10++;}
        else if(slopeChanges.get(i) == 1) {count_neg11++;}
      } 

      else if (slopeChanges.get(j) == 1) {
        if (slopeChanges.get(i) == 0) {count_10++;}
        else if(slopeChanges.get(i) == -1) {count_1neg1++;}
      } 

      else if (slopeChanges.get(j) == 0) {
        if (slopeChanges.get(i) == -1) {count_0neg1++;}
        else if(slopeChanges.get(i) == 1) {count_01++;}
      }
      j = i;
    }

    System.out.println(slopeChanges);

    if(count_neg10 != 0) {
      System.out.println("count_neg10 = " + count_neg10);
      sixProbabilites.add((double)count_neg10 / ((double)slopeChanges.size()));
    }
    if(count_neg11 != 0) {
      System.out.println("count_neg11 = " + count_neg11);
      sixProbabilites.add((double)count_neg11 / ((double)slopeChanges.size()));
    }
    if(count_10 != 0)    {
      System.out.println("count_10 = " + count_10);
      sixProbabilites.add((double)count_10 / ((double)slopeChanges.size()));
    }
    if(count_1neg1 != 0) {
      System.out.println("count_1neg1 = " + count_1neg1);
      sixProbabilites.add((double)count_1neg1 / ((double)slopeChanges.size()));
    }
    if(count_0neg1 != 0) {
      System.out.println("count_0neg1 = " + count_0neg1);
      sixProbabilites.add((double)count_0neg1 / ((double)slopeChanges.size()));
    }
    if(count_01 != 0)    {
      System.out.println("count_01 = " + count_01);
      sixProbabilites.add((double)count_01 / ((double)slopeChanges.size()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking the  response from @Adam_Silenko as a new base (`j` is like a *previous circular index*) and doing some change to generalize the algorithm.

You have some options:

Using a switch statement to decrease the number of branch, with some magic formula:

```
//...
for(int i = 0, j = slopeChanges.size() -1; i<slopeChanges.size(); i++) {
  switch (2* slopeChanges.get(j) - slopeChanges.get(i)) {
    case 2* (-1)-( 0): count_neg10++; break;
    case 2* (-1)-( 1): count_neg11++; break;
    case 2* ( 0)-(-1): count_0neg1++; break;
    case 2* ( 0)-( 1): count_01++;  break;
    case 2* ( 1)-(-1): count_1neg1++; break;
    case 2* ( 1)-( 0): count_10++;  break;
  }
  j = i;
}
//...
```

Or, maybe more short and efficient, using a two dimensional array (and incrementing the value since an index can't be negative):

```
// ...
int[][] count = new int[3][3];
for(int i = 0, j = slopeChanges.size() -1; i<slopeChanges.size(); i++) {
  count[slopeChanges.get(j)+1][slopeChanges.get(i)+1]++;
  j = i;
}
// ...
```

Or even, mix the two methods, using a simple array where the index comes from a formula like in the first option.

After that, you surely have to encapsulate the logic of your algorithm (`counting` and `results`) into classes with a good interface, for usability.